# Twilio Node.js API - Trouble using 'Dial' to forward call

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I'm having some trouble getting 'Dial' to work to forward a call using the Twilio Node.js Library. There's little documentation for this library, and the only example using 'Dial' is for conference calls:

```
.dial({
            action:'http://example.com/something.php'
        }, function(node) {
            node.conference('waitingRoom', {
            beep:'false'
        });
    });
```

Using this, I have been able to produce similar XML as in the [Dial Documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/dial#attributes) using the following:

```
.dial('number', {
                  action: 'http://url'
                  hangupOnStar: true
                }, (err, respData) => {
                  console.log(err);
                  console.log(respData);
                })
```

This results in the call being immediately forwarded to the `action` url.

I've also tried using the third example on their documentation, `Example 3: Dial to a phone number from Twilio Client`, which produces the following XML:

```
<Response>
    <Dial hangupOnStar="true" callerId="number">
        <Number>number to call</Number>
    </Dial>
</Response>
```

through the following code:

```
resp.dial({
                  hangupOnStar: true,
                  callerId: 'number'
                }, (node) => {
                  node.number('number')
                })
```

These numbers I'm testing with are valid numbers, and I've also tried different formats. Any ideas how to get this working? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To forward a call , a flow could be something like

1. Set up the voice URL for your Twilio number to an endpoint that gives TwiML Response back when this Twilio Number receives a call .
2. In this endpoint the TwiML Response should `<Dial>` the `<Number>` where you want to forward the call to . This would bridge the incoming call i.e. forward it to your desired number.

I have mentioned below a sample code that could do this in

```
app.get("/forwardToMyMobile",function(i_Req,o_Res)
   {
               var ivrTwilRes = new twilio.TwimlResponse();
               var numberToForwardCallTo=i_Req.query.toNumber; 
               /*In case you want to pass this number as querystring ,
                 else if its a fixed number you can just hardcode it */


              ivrTwilRes.dial({callerId:'+44xxxxxxxx'},
                                function()
                                             {
                                                  this.number(numberToForwardCallTo);

                                             }
                                        )
                           .record();

               o_Res.set('Content-Type','text/xml');
               o_Res.send(ivrTwilRes.toString());
   });
```

When your Twilio number receives the call now , it will webhook to "/forwardToMyMobile" on your nodejs server application and instruct Twilio to forward the call.